# java aes 256 java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size after installation the policy

Tags: java, encryption, aes, sha256

i have a problem with the encrypt of the bytes with an AES 256 key.
I already installed the policy. Here's what I've done:

1. download the file: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html
2. I moved the files local_policy and US_export_policy to the directory /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
3. i restart the mac

But still I get an error message with the following code:

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(256);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
Cipher decryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
decryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, 
new IvParameterSpec(secretKey.getEncoded())); // <-- Illegal key size
```

My Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

What i have to do, to use the 256 AES encryption?

Comment: Code should be properly formatted. Why did you roll back my edit that repaired your format?

Comment: sry, I didn´t know that you've edited my text.

Comment: OK, I put the fix back.

Comment: Please don't use the key as IV - you will open up to a chosen-ciphertext attack which recovers the key. If you must use a fixed IV, 0 would be safer.

Comment: Thanks, but why should I use no padding? If the key length is not known, then it would be safer, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Policy files should resolve the issue. Check the path environment variable to confirm that you are using the same jre which has policy files.

Comment: i checked my $JAVA_HOME (result: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home") or i started my java program with following command: " / Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java-jar sec_test.jar", but it doesn't work. After that i copied the policy file in the other directory ("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin"), i was able to start the program. Ok it works, but why? I checked the path to ire and i have started the program explicitly with this JRE 1.7.0_40. Are there any other settings of JRE?

Comment: Check the $PATH environment variable, you will find which java is configured for your environement

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTANT: you have know you jre location. eg: in my compute have `C:\Java\jre7\lib\security` and `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\lib\security`, but eclipse show the jre is `C:\Java\jre7\lib\security`,so you must copy two file into here.

Answer (score 1):

What I did 
   downloaded policy file from this location 
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

paste in location 
`jre/lib/security/`
and it workes....