# java.security AES encryption key length

Tags: java, encryption, aes

When the key length is 128 bits,everything works. But I got the following exception when I use a key of length 192 or 256 bits.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
```

I found this [Java Security: Illegal key size or default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters). But after I download the jar files and put it in `${java.home}/lib/security/`, I still got the same exception.

Answer (score 15):

Java comes with a default maximum strength of 128 bits.

What you need is a set of files called **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files** and is currently available at the [Java SE download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). This zip file contains a couple of policy jars, which you need copy over the top of the ones already in the **{java.home}/jre/lib/security** directory of your JRE.

This will let you change the key strength above 128 bits

Comment: But I download the jar files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html, and put it under ${java.home}/lib/security/, still got the exception.

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is to put those jar files on the lib/security dir of the JRE which is running the java program

Comment: @Cacheing Make sure they go in ${java.home}/jre/lib/security, not as you said above ${java.home}/lib/security

Comment: @Christian The key size is limited to 128 **bits** not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

What Java implementation are you using?

If you look at the docs (like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)), you can see that they might only support specific key lengths. This one only supports 128 bit.