# java decrytpion & c# encryption Illegal key size issue

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, aes

We were encrypting/decrypting our organization's document from this code by a c# application

```
var msData = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = null;
            if (inputFileStream.CanSeek)
                inputFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            try
            {
                long inputFileLength = inputFileStream.Length;
                var byteBuffer = new byte[4096];
                long bytesProcessed = 0;
                int bytesInCurrentBlock = 0;

                var csRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
                switch (action)
                {
                    case CryptoAction.Encrypt:
                        cs = new CryptoStream(msData, csRijndael.CreateEncryptor(this.Key, this.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                        break;

                    case CryptoAction.Decrypt:
                        cs = new CryptoStream(msData, csRijndael.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                        break;
                }

                while (bytesProcessed < inputFileLength)
                {
                    bytesInCurrentBlock = inputFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 4096);
                    cs.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesInCurrentBlock);
                    bytesProcessed += bytesInCurrentBlock;
                }
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                return msData.ToArray();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                new Com.Library.SqlLog().InsertSqlLog(Auth.currentMemberInfo.LoginId, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
                return null;
            }
```

and it is working fine.Now I am creating a Java application which is supposed to decrypt these documents too.Initially I tried to decrypt documents by this code of Java

```
 try{


    AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV); 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyGen, "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec); 
    byte[] output =  new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(new String(convertDocToByteArra("//Path/somePDF.pdf")));  

     byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(output);

     convertByteArrayToDoc(decrypted);
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Now here is my problem.I passed this as init vector

```
static byte IV[] = new byte[] {0x0E,0x15,(byte)0xC4,(byte)0xBB,
             (byte)0xEE,(byte)0xDF,0x72,0x0C,0x4F,0x7E,(byte)0xBE,0x67,0x4A,(byte)0xB6,0x45,(byte)0xDE};
```

and this as a key

```
static byte[] keyGen = new byte[]{0x78,(byte)0x9C,(byte)0xF1,0x01,0x12,0x31,(byte)0xCD,0x1E,0x1F,0x16,0x54,0x19,0x1D,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xC7,
            0x00,0x51,(byte)0xBF,(byte)0xFD,0x31,(byte)0xE1,(byte)0xA1,(byte)0xDC,(byte)0xC9,0x23,0x49,(byte)0xAD,0x11,0x16,0x17,0x1D,0x1F};
```

But when I run this program then it throws an exception given below

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1023)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:789)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:848)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1347)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1281)
    at DecryptAspEncryptedDocs.main(DecryptAspEncryptedDocs.java:80)
```

Now I am stuck here and don't know what to do.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters) and jars are placed in jre/lib/security and jdk/lib/security.But still issue is pending and throwing `illegal key size` exception

Comment: Works for me (when I change the mode to CBC that is).

Comment: @GregS I have provided AES/CBC/NoPadding but it is again saying "Illegal keysize"

Comment: As I said it works for me and I know I have the unlimited crypto policy jars installed. It seems like that you do not, despite your beliefs. Perhaps you have multiple versions of Java installed, or you have mis-installed the policy files.

Comment: Can you post your code for help.May be I was doing wrong somewhere

Comment: I just used your code. I copy&pasted the lines from your example up to and including the `cipher.init()` line and copy&pasted your keyGen and IV.

Comment: @GregS can the policy files limitation can be overcome by using BouncyCastle API ?

Comment: @dakait: Yes, if you use the Bouncycastle lightweight API. That's different than using the JCE APIs with the Bouncycastle provider. The latter won't help at all.

Comment: @GregS ok, tnx for your time

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the key size for AES then it will be subject to export controls. I suggest that you download the unlimited jce jurisdiction policy files and install them into your Java environment.

AES256 will require the unlimited the policy files.

Comment: yes I aleady did that by reviewing this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters

Answer (score 0):

It's not stated clearly in README that "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" should be copied to jre inside your JDK, otherwise it would not work. Path for files should be: /path/to/jdk1.7.0_xx/jre/lib/security