# Please Help-Stuck Invalid Key Exception

Tags: java, security, cryptography, aes, public-key-encryption

I am getting  java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters , I have fallow all the required step ,Installed  Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.
Also I have Gone through these Threads

[Java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters error](http://www.coderanch.com/t/521137/Security/java-security-InvalidKeyException-Illegal-key)

[Java Security: Illegal key size or default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters)

But I am still stuck and getting  java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters ,

Below is My Code :
AESKeyGenerator.java

```
public class AESKeyGenerator {

    private Cipher mCipher;

    public AESKeyGenerator()
    {
        // default constructor
    }


    public byte[] generate_k(String dhkey, String toEncrypt)
    {
        byte[] retVal;

        try { // Set up the Cipher class of Android to use AES to generate keys
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            for (int i = 0; i < iv.length; i++)
                iv[i] = new Byte("0").byteValue();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // Set up key to use in algorithm
            MessageDigest hasher = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); // Initialize object that will hash my key.
            byte[] key256 = hasher.digest(dhkey.getBytes()); // Hash the key to 256 bits using SHA
            SecretKeySpec K = new SecretKeySpec(key256, "AES");
            System.out.println("SecretKeySpec : "+K  + "  key256 "+key256);
            mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, K, ivspec);
            // Encrypt the parameter toEncrypt
            retVal = mCipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
            return retVal;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Could not create and initialize object Cipher.");
        }

        return null;

    }

    public byte[] generate_r(byte[] sharedKey, String toEncrypt)
    {
        byte[] retVal;
        try {
            /*byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            for (int i = 0; i < iv.length; i++)
                iv[i] = new Byte("0").byteValue();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);*/

            // Set up the Cipher class of Android to use AES to generate keys
            mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            // Set up key to use in algorithm
            MessageDigest hasher = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); // Initialize object that will hash my key.
            byte[] key256 = hasher.digest(sharedKey); // Hash the key to 256 bits using SHA 256
            SecretKeySpec K = new SecretKeySpec(key256, "AES");
            mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, K);
            // Encrypt the parameter toEncrypt
            System.out.println("toEncrypt AES: "+ toEncrypt);
            retVal = mCipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
            return retVal;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("exception: "+ e.toString());
            System.err.println("Could not create and initialize object Cipher.");
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

**I am getting fallowing error:**

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1010)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:785)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:848)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1212)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1152)
  at AESKeyGenerator.generate_r(AESKeyGenerator.java:74)
  at DetectionServer.storeGridInformation(DetectionServer.java:309)
  at DetectionServer.doPost(DetectionServer.java:103)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
exception: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
Could not create and initialize object Cipher.
```

I check with the standard code which is also same as this. I think there is some issue with configuration or missing library.

Comment: You have a comment: `// Set up the Cipher class of Android`. Did you just copy/paste that from somewhere or is this code running in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can *not* reproduce this - I have installed the current [Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and I have used the following main method to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
   AESKeyGenerator aes = new AESKeyGenerator();
   String sharedKey = "Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345";
   aes.generate_r(sharedKey.getBytes("US-ASCII"), "Hello World");
}
```

Prior to installing the policy files, I got the same exception as you.

One thing I did wrong first is that I installed the policy files into `Program files/jdk_1.7.0_13/jre/lib/security`, but the JRE which was used is located in `Program files/jre7` - so make sure that you have installed the policy files in the proper location and check with a simple standalone java application using the main method above if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas, I was doing the same mistake,installed the policy files into Program files/jdk_1.7.0_13/jre/lib/security, but the JRE which was used is located in Program files/jre7... When I installed these files in files/jre7 Its works :)

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem but it works fine now,,you have to go to this site and download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html
download(UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip) then extract it and copy the two jar file to your jdk location path and restart your project. that's it