# Correct Parameters to pass to Encrypt AES in Coldfusion 8 (or 10)

Tags: coldfusion, aes

So I have (this doesn’t work b/c hex is probably wrong and the key and the IV are not converted correctly):

(aesKey and aesIV are provided as hex strings from Third Party)

They look something like this (not the same but should be enough to work with I replaced some values in the keys so they aren’t exactly the same:

```
<cfparam name="aesKey" default="C20648780E8843795325F3BA5EC43183C8BFA2D26B5470BC309ED5BA6B142EFA"/>
<cfparam name="aesIV" default="A53F0A6E6972A0095CFFDBE4F47C3CF8"/>

<cfset token = Encrypt(encryptString, aesKey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex", aesIV)>
```

The error is:

*The key specified is not a valid key for this encryption: Illegal key size or default parameters.*

(I’m also not sure “hex” is right)

I also have this from third party

> Third Party uses the following parameters for AES encryption:
>   Block Length                                      256bit
>   Padding                                                PKCS7
>   Cipher mode                                      CBC
>   Key Length                                         256bit (to be provided by Third Party in hexadecimal format)
>   Initialization Vector Length          128bit (to be provided by Third Party in hexadecimal format)
>
> The secret (private) key and the initialization vector are used to perform AES encryption on the plaintext token. The encrypted string is then passed to Third Party SSO process where it is decrypted with the matching key and initialization vector.

So I’m not doing any formatting or converting with the key or the iv but the error suggests that I need to manage it.

But that’s where I’m guessing (it does want a string it’s just the string I’m passing is wrong)

I know I’m close and I do have a “Whatever it takes to make it work” solution (where I go from CF to .net and use the sample code provided) but I don’t want to do that, . . . but I do have it. (This would be the second time I went from language B back to language A because I have something that works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things you must do in order to get it work:

1. By default, you are limited to 128bit keys for AES. To use larger keys, like 256bit, you must first install the [(JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html), or [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) / [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) (depending on your JRE version). Copy them into your `/lib/security/` directory. (Note: If you have multiple JVM's installed, be sure you update the jars in the correct one ie The one listed in the CF Administrator). Then restart the CF server.
2. `Encrypt()` expects keys to be in base64 format. So use [binaryDecode/Encode](http://cfquickdocs.com/#BinaryEncode) to convert the key from hex to base64:

   `<cfset base64Key = binaryEncode(binaryDecode(yourHexKey, "hex"), "base64") />`
3. The `iv` should be in binary. Again, use binaryDecode to convert it:

   `<cfset binaryIV = binaryDecode(yourHexIV, "hex")  />`

Once you have made those changes, your code should work fine:

```
Encrypt(encryptString, base64Key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex", binaryIV)
```

(Despite the antiquated version in the title, I have found [this article on strong encryption](https://web.archive.org/web/20150105220023/http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html) to be a great reference for troubleshooting encryption issues)

Comment: Very helpful! Note that the JCE download depends on the JRE version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters

Comment: @DavidHammond - Yep, good point. I updated the answer to make it more obvious.