# Still getting Illegal key size or default parameters after adding required .jar files

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I am facing the following `SSL` connection `exception` when trying to connect to remote server:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
```

As suggetested by this thread: [**Java Security: Illegal key size or default parameters?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters)

I download the `Unlimited Strength` jar files ( `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` )

**for where should I place them I did the following:**

1. Following the Installation instruction I should place them in `Java home` folder as follow :

   `<java-home>\lib\security` but still getting the same error.
2. Also, I tried to add them to `IDE` home folder in my case `JDeveloper 10.1.3.2` which is: `...\jdevstudio10132\jdk\jre\lib\security`and here is what happened:

   - The folder has the `.jar` files already and when I replace them with the updated versions I am getting the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA12275)`

Comment: Should be `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`, not `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security`.

Comment: I did that still the issue is not resolved