# OSX: env variable is not available

Tags: macos, environment-variables

In my gradle project, I am using Dropwizard Crypto for encrypting passwords. I have added the passphrase to IntelliJ env variable and when running "gradlew run" task got the error that can't decrypt. 
I have also added the env variable to ~/.bash_profile and run the IntelliJ from terminal and got same error. It works perfectly fine on Windows but on Mac not working (My os is Sierra 10.12)
I have tried running the gradlew run task from terminal and got same error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I debugged and went deeper and found out that this was the issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be in

```
~/.bash_profile (with a dot)
```

or

```
~/.profile
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to have the . in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
export IntelliJ=passphrase
```

from a terminal session and run gradlew from the same session.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. 
In terminal if I echo the value it will show the password. but gradlew run from IntelliJ and command line not working