# Issue with Robolectric with cipher in android application

Tags: android, encryption, robolectric, sqlcipher-android

Hi I am using Robolectric for test cases. I am facing some issue while simulating for encryption relateed test cases. I tried to use cipher with AES for encryption. And it is giving me some error. I tried it in following manner :

```
    @Test
public void testGet() {
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        SecretKey sks= getKeySpec(pass, salt);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public SecretKey getKeySpec(char[] pass, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    //generate key spec...
    return secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
}
```

It gives me following error :

```
Illegal key size or default parameters
```

I already added `JCE` for illegal size exception. It is working if I run it on device and properly working in my application. Only thing when I try with robolectric it is giving me this error.Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Nilkash. Did you solve this Issue?

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this is Robolectric runs on JVM. JVM supports up to 128 bit key encryption only. Therefore if you are using 256 bit key encryption you need to use Java Cryptography Extension (JCE). [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters/6481658#6481658) to how to do that