# Openssl -aes-256-cbc in java with only provided key

Tags: java, encryption, openssl

when I decrypt the file by using command line tool `openssl`, it is OK by the following commend.
I don't any information about the encryption, client only provide the following command and key.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in 8MP_2018_12_12.gz.enc -out 8MP_2018_12_12.gz.enc.gz -pass file:pass.txt
```

I already check a lot question in stackoverflow , test and run for a lot of program. As I have only provided key, I cannot use `ivparameterspec`.

In pass.txt, there is a provided key

```
xxxxxxx12354125222sdsf <- example
```

My Program

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.ssl.OpenSSL;

public class OpenSSLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File inputFile = new File("D:\\temp\\8MP_2018_12_12.gz.enc");
        File outputFile = new File("D:\\temp\\8MP_2018_12_12.gz");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        InputStream in = OpenSSL.decrypt("aes-256-cbc", "xxxxxxx12354125222sdsf".toCharArray(), inputStream);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        IOUtils.copy(in, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

When I run above program, I get the following message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.PKCS8Key.generateCipher(PKCS8Key.java:420)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.OpenSSL.decrypt(OpenSSL.java:165)
    at OpenSSLTest.main(OpenSSLTest.java:15)
```

I already try to fixed that issue according to [Java Security: Illegal key size or default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters)

I already download `jce_policy-8.zip`. I already put `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` into my `....\jre1.8.0_66\lib\security` directory.

I still get above error message. My JDK version is jdk1.8.0_66.

Answer (score 1):

The "key" string you're getting from `pass.txt` is 22 characters. When OpenSSL uses a "password" to derive a key, it uses the [`EVP_BytesToKey` algorithm](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) to determine the actual (AES, in this case) key to use. That key must be 16, 24, or 32 bytes (128, 192, or 256 bits respectively).

I don't know how the library you're using derives the key from the provided password, but it doesn't seem to be doing that correctly, or if it is, 256 bit keys are not enabled in this JVM instance. One thing to check is that unless you renamed the `jre` directory, the directory path should actually look like `jdk_1.8.0_66\jre\lib\security`. You can use this code snippet to test the key lengths available to you:

```
if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") > 128) {
    System.out.println("All key lengths supported");
} else {
    System.out.println("Only 128 bit keys supported");
}
```