# PDFBox throwing exception java.io.IOException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

Tags: java, pdfbox, jce

I am trying PDFBox for merging multiple PDF documents. Code is below.
I am facing an issue. For a few PDF files I am getting "`java.io.IOException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`".
 I am not sure what is going on. Could someone please help me ?

```
PDFMergerUtility PDFutility = new PDFMergerUtility();
ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PDFutility.addSources(pdfDocs);
PDFutility.setDestinationStream(mergedPdf);
PDFutility.mergeDocuments();
```

**The Error**

> ```
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.computeEncryptedKeyRev56(StandardSecurityHandler.java:779)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.computeEncryptedKey(StandardSecurityHandler.java:681)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.prepareForDecryption(StandardSecurityHandler.java:256)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.prepareDecryption(COSParser.java:2929)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.retrieveTrailer(COSParser.java:286)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:173)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:226)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1222)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1140)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:455)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:346)
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:330)
> ```

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Probably an old version and you have not updated it with the unlimited strength policy for security related algorithms?

Comment: I am using v 1.7. I agree that JCE needs an upgrade but I get problems with only a few pdfs not all of them. Could this be related to PDF file ?

Comment: PDF supports different encryption methods, some of them ridiculously simple to break. Probably only some of your PDFs are encrypted and only some of those encrypted PDFs are encrypted using a strong algorithm.

Comment: Is there a way i can find the encryption ? I need a strong reason to upgrade JCE.

Comment: Asked and answered http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4808, and [Java Security: Illegal key size or default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481627/java-security-illegal-key-size-or-default-parameters). The "strong reason" is that you won't be able to open these PDFs without strong crypto capability.

Comment: *"I need a strong reason to upgrade JCE"* - if you don't at least install the unlimited strength policy (or use an equivalent hack), signatures and encryption available to you aren't worth a dime. If your use case does not require security and can cope with rejecting files applying stronger security, you don't need to upgrade.